# How to properly execute this while loop in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

```
#!/bin/bash

f=1
c=$1
while [[ $c != 0 ]]
do
        $f=$(($c*$f))
        $c=$(($c-1))
done
echo $c
```

I keep getting the error

```
./process.sh: line 8: 1=0: command not found
./process.sh: line 7: 5=5: command not found
```

When running `./process.sh 5`

Comment: Your loop starts with `c=1` and then runs while `c!=0` and it subtracts `1` from c each time? That's not much of a loop.

Comment: I changed the mistake

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$` means "value of" so `$f` gets evaluated to the string literal `1`. So...

```
    $f=$(($c*$f))
    $c=$(($c-1))
```

should be

```
    f=$(($c*$f))
    c=$(($c-1))
```

Answer (score 1):

in the loop, it should be

```
f=$(($c*$f))
c=$(($c-1))
```